# Excel VBA question

Tags: excel, vba

I need to quickly learn Excel VBA for a project I will be working on. I have some (classic) VB experience, as well as programming experience in C, C++ etc - though I don't know much about the dotNet languages.

Can anyone recommend a good book that will allow me to hit the ground running in terms of Excel development - given my background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a zillion books on this subject in any given bookstore (in fact, more books on Excel VBA than any other single technology in the average bookstore), but if you're looking for the definitive Excel VBA book, go with [VBA and Macros for Microsoft Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/store/index.php?l=product_detail&p=49) by Mr. Excel (disclaimer: I have no affiliation to that company whatsoever).

You don't need to know a thing about .NET to work with VBA. Your C++/C experience won't really come in handy all that much, other than just knowing how to ensure you don't have lazy VBA code. Your classic VB experience is what will help the most - but just keep in mind that it's really understanding Excel's object model that will be the learning curve here. Once you really get into it, it is pretty straight-forward though.

Comment: If OP also uses the Macro recorder and Google for your questions/ideas, you can get pretty far.  Combining that with a book/website will get him off and running.  There's also [Chandoo.org](http://chandoo.org/wp/) has been helpful for me in the past.

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could _maybe_ be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Comment: Feel free to delete the answer then. Why are you commenting 11 years later?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked previously:

[what is a good up-to-date book for an experienced developer to learn excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404824/what-is-a-good-up-to-date-book-for-an-experienced-developer-to-learn-excel-vba/404836#404836)

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2013 Power Programming with VBA. By: John Walkenbach

The VBA language itself isn't an issue. The problem is more understanding the object model for the respective office product.